# Zoom Button transparency Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am working with achartengine for displaying some graphs. In my app I show two graphs in each screen and legend is overlaping with the zoom buttons. Is it possible to change size and/or transparency of the zoom buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the zoom buttons.

```
renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
```

Or you can increase the margins.

```
renderer.setMargins();
```

Dan